# How to access and change the input tag title?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tags, title

Here is my HTML 5 code:

```html
<input 
    id="submitting" 
    type="submit" 
    value="Submit" 
    class="btn btn-success" 
    data-toggle="tooltip" 
    title="<img src='images/Item-1.jpg' class='img-responsive'/>" 
    data-placement="right" 
    data-html="true" 
/>
```

While browsing with development tools, I've found that title doesn't represent the string in the source but data-original-title.

```html
<input 
    id="submitting" 
    type="submit" 
    value="Submit" 
    class="btn btn-success" 
    data-toggle="tooltip" 
    title="" 
    data-placement="right" 
    data-html="true" 
    data-original-title="&lt;img src='images/Item-1.jpg' class='img-responsive'/&gt;"
/>
```

I need to change the title to present a different image each time. I've tried everything I've found but obviously I'm missing something.

Comment: You can't put tags inside your title attribute.

Comment: What exactly do you want in title? Because title normaly should only contain text. If you want some kind of image to show when hovering over the input you should use javascript to do so.

Comment: Are you using a plugin?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask : "Post the question and respond to feedback. After you post, leave the question open in your browser for a bit, and see if anyone comments. If you missed an obvious piece of information, be ready to respond by editing your question to include it. If someone posts an answer, be ready to try it out and provide feedback!".

Comment: Thanks for sharing! No matter how much you try that it wont ever work.

Comment: Do you use some kind of library to replace the data-original-title i realy don't seem to understand what you want here.

Comment: @procrastinator Nope, to the OP. Unless you're using more than one account hmmmm....

Comment: The HTML code represent a simple bootstrap 3 tooltip with image on hover. what I was trying to do is to change the image upon some events. It seems like I don't have a method for it in Bootstrap and it conflicts with Jquery UI

Comment: What kept you @voyager? I guess you were on a trip... Well, why not having mentioned Bootstrap into your question? Would you mind to edit your question in order to reply to comments [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22100274/how-to-access-and-change-the-input-tag-title#comment33522566_22100274), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22100274/how-to-access-and-change-the-input-tag-title#comment33522602_22100274), etc...? At the same time, could you provide a link to this Bootstrap tooltip in order for us to see it in action? That would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [jQuery UI tooltip](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/):

**HTML**:

```
<input 
    id="submitting" 
    type="submit" 
    value="Submit" 
    class="btn btn-success"
    title=""
/>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#submitting").tooltip({ content: '<img src="images/Item-1.jpg"  class="img-responsive" />' });
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chridam/9DGBW/)**

Comment: I realy forgot about the tooltip :)

Comment: @Marcio I think that's what the OP is after :)

Comment: Thanks. any reason for using jquery 1.9.1 with jquery ui 1.9.2 ? in your example it doesn't work in the newer versions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use jQuery library for that but basicaly you should do something like this. `title` is supposed to contain text.

http://plnkr.co/edit/UQcBV2aHfZuyzYwWebXk?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can access title using...

```
jQuery("input").prop("title");
```

And you can change title using...

```
jQuery("input").prop("title", "Insert New Title");
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Guys sometime I want to kick myself.
while using bootstrap 3 and Jquery the best answqe I've found that works is :

```
var title=$("#submitting").attr('data-original-title');
$("#submitting").attr("title","data-original-title"); //making sure
$("#submitting").attr("data-original-title","some image" class='img-responsive'/>");
```

Thanks all